# React bootstrap modal how to send post request first and then close modal when submitting values

Tags: reactjs, post, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, submit

I'm making a form in a bootstrap modal. When you press submit the form data should be posted and the modal should close. The way my code is structured now the modal closes but I think my request doesn't have enough time to emit the post request because is never sends. When I remove the `this.props.onHide` form submit button. The request does get send and obviously the modal doesn't close.

Anyone have an idea how I can send the Post request and also close the modal?

button that opens modal:

```
export default function SidenavButtons(props) {
    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}>{props.usage}</a>
            <CreateServiceModal
                show={modalShow}
                onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                modelUsage= {props.usage}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

modal footer --> submit button:

```
                               <Modal.Footer>
                                    <Mutation mutation={POST_MUTATION}
                                        variables={{ cost, name, description, hours, minutes }}>

                                        {postMutation =>
                                            <button onClick={postMutation , this.props.onHide}>Submit</button>

                                        }
                                    </Mutation>
                                </Modal.Footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call multiple functions upon a single button click, simply use an inline arrow function and call your fav functions separated by `;`

```js
{
  (postMutation) => (
    <button onClick={() => {postMutation(); this.props.onHide()}}>Submit</button>
  );
}
```